# How to list data in a table according to ID after getting it from different source in javascript?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, javascript-objects

I have 3 sources (A,B,C) to get different data but they have a common field PID and those 3 sources are independent. Like, when I presenting this data on UI may be parameter of B can be change but it will return data with PID.
Whatever, what changes happened into the Sources it should adjust with other column and need to show data according to PID.

*Getting Data from source:*

A : pid, name, data_a

B : pid, data_b

C : pid, data_c

*Presentation Should be:*

**pid - data_a - data_b - data_c**

1 -----23 ------34-------35

2 -----24-------45-------56

I was thinking about index about may be in third source the value of  pid-2 is blank.

Any suggestion regarding this issue?

**Sample Data format:**

var sourceA = [{ pid: 1, data_a: 23, data_x: 23},{ pid: 2, data_a: 23 ,data_x: 23}];

var sourceB = [{ pid: 1, data_b: 34, data_y: 34 },{ pid: 2, data_b: 34, data_y: 34 }];

var sourceC = [{ pid: 1, data_c: 35, data_z: 34 },{ pid: 2, data_c: 35, data_z: 34 }];

**Edit::**

```html
var sourceA = [{ pid: 1, data_a: 23, data_x: 23},{ pid: 2, data_a: 23 ,data_x: 23}];

var sourceB = [{ pid: 1, data_a: 34, data_x: 34 },{ pid: 2, data_a: 34, data_x: 34 }];

var sourceC = [{ pid: 1, data_a: 35, data_x: 34 },{ pid: 2, data_a: 35, data_x: 34 }];
```

and I want it like that :

```html
[
  {
    "pid": 1,
    "array": [
      {
        "data_a": 33,
        "data_x": 30
      },
      {
        "data_a": 33,
        "data_x": 30
      },
      {
        "data_a": 33,
        "data_x": 30
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "pid": 2,
    "array": [
      {
        "data_a": 33,
        "data_x": 30
      },
      {
        "data_a": 33,
        "data_x": 30
      },
      {
        "data_a": 33,
        "data_x": 30
      }
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ECMAScript6's Object.assign:

```js
sourceA = { pid: 1, data_a: 23 };
sourceB = { pid: 1, data_b: 34 };
sourceC = { pid: 1, data_c: 35 };

var result = Object.assign({}, sourceA, sourceB, sourceC);
console.log(result);
```

EDIT:

In case sources are array, it should be:

```js
var sourceA = [{ pid: 1, data_a: 23, data_x: 23},{ pid: 2, data_a: 23 ,data_x: 23}]; 
var sourceB = [{ pid: 1, data_b: 34, data_y: 34 },{ pid: 2, data_b: 34, data_y: 34 }]; 
var sourceC = [{ pid: 1, data_c: 35, data_z: 34 },{ pid: 2, data_c: 35, data_z: 34 }];

var result = sourceA.map((obj, index) => Object.assign({}, sourceA[index], sourceB[index], sourceC[index])); 
console.log(result);
```

Comment: var sourceA = [{ pid: 1, data_a: 23, data_x: 23},{ pid: 2, data_a: 23 ,data_x: 23}];
var sourceB = [{ pid: 1, data_b: 34, data_y: 34 },{ pid: 2, data_b: 34, data_y: 34 }];
var sourceC = [{ pid: 1, data_c: 35, data_z: 34 },{ pid: 2, data_c: 35, data_z: 34 }];

What it would be when it is like that ?

Comment: I need more help. :)
Can you check it now.